# load gif image while loading the other page using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

is there any way that loading GIF image while onclick and simultaneously, navigation should happen.
i tried this way..

```
     $("#Videop").click(function ()
 {
     //till the time the post function below doesn't return the following image will be displayed
     tactile.page.getComponent("loadingnext").show();
     $.post("http://cloud.netbiscuits.net/1305494/SyngentaMobileStage/aspx/Video.aspx",
         function (data)
         {
             //get the new HTML content
             $("#root").html(data);
         });

 });
```

but how about the script files and background function calls associated with that page?

Comment: what does the `data` returns?? for navigating the page use `window.location.href("www.google.com");`

Comment: if i use window.location.href("www.google.com") then navigation will happen but some browsers doesn.t animate gif image, so i found one way to load content using ajax but scrript file css and background calls are not calling which is assosciated to loading page.

Comment: so what does the `data` contains? a whole html page???

Comment: yeah whole html page..

Comment: that is a **very bad practice**

Comment: so what is the solution?? i tried different ways but no animation while page redirection was happening.

Comment: whats the logic of having a **loading GIF image** if your server is **really fast** to load the page you wanted??

Comment: generally our page are completely dynamic and not that much fast because of huge data, so if loading image is shown then its implies something was processing and that was an  requirement for us.

Answer (score 0):

what I understood from your question is, to redirect when `#Videop` is clicked and show a **loading GIF image**

```
$("#Videop").click(function ()
 {     //till the time the post function below doesn't return the following image will be displayed
     tactile.page.getComponent("loadingnext").show();
     window.location.href('http://cloud.netbiscuits.net/1305494/SyngentaMobileStage/aspx/Video.aspx');
 });
```

The above code will show the GIF image, until your page is redirected. Now you will not have the head ache of bringing all the `css` and `script` files from that page to here.

**EDIT:**

in your new page `Video.aspx` add this, hope this will solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Display your GIF Image
    //tactile.page.getComponent("loadingnext").show(); 
    console.log("I'm loading");
});

jQuery(window).load(function () {
    //Hide your GIF image
   // tactile.page.getComponent("loadingnext").hide(); 
    console.log('page is loaded');
});
```

Comment: i tried this approach but i saw no animation while redirecting in android native browser.

Comment: have you tried `tactile.page.getComponent("loadingnext").show();` some where in `console` and see whether the GIF image is shown?

Comment: in console its showing, when google it some people told some browsers cant handle this syncronous calls and take the href attribute , i tried stopping out 2 seconds so that loader will animate for 2 seconds after it will show like static image and navigation will proceed after 2 seconds.

Comment: you want the GIF image to show in the **redirected page** until its fully loaded??

Comment: no, what i want is when a link is clicked navigation as well as gif loading should happen. please check this page `http://cloud.netbiscuits.net/1305494/SyngentaMobileStage/` and click on any link

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a progress function, and show a waiting image before ajax starts, and hide after ajax ends.

1. Add a element hidden in the body tag, that could be a image or a loading div.
2. Define a function.
3. Call it before and after ajax.

Here is a small demo, hopes to help you out.

```
#loading{display:none;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
<div id="loading">loading...</div>
$.progress = function(stop){
    if(stop){
        $('#loading').hide();
    } else {
        $('#loading').show();
    }
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){
        $.progress();
    }, complete: function(){
        $.progress(true);
    }
});
```

You can change the style by yourself.

jsfiddler was down, I can not write code, sorry about that. :D